# Improper validation when installing Oracle Fusion Middleware

Tags: oracle11g, websphere, oracle-fusion-middleware

I installed Oracle JDeveloper 11g (11.1.1.4.0). I also installed IBM Websphere 7.0.0.15 without any profile as suggested in the documentation. Next I wanted to install Oracle Fusion Middleware 11g. But during installation, I was asked Application Server Location for which I gave

> C:\Program
>   Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7

When I click next, I am getting this error

> INST-07004: Application Server
>   Location location contains one or more
>   invalid characters. The directory name
>   may only contain alphanumeric,
>   underscore(_), hyphen(-), or dot(.)
>   characters, and it must begin with an
>   alphanumeric charater. Provide a
>   different directory name.

Server location is proper and link specified satisfies condition. I dont understand why I am getting that error. If it is because of : in the location, how else do I specify the path ? Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using WAS Test Environment. After I tried with standalone WAS, it succeeded but I am not able to configure after install. The changes are not being saved to WAS.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a path which does not contain spaces